# Get (ONLY) the city name from coordinates in Android

Tags: android, location

As the title writes, I would like to get the name of city (only) and not the address from coordinates. I find the code below but it returns me all the address and not only the city.

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        int maxLines = address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex();
        for (int i=0; i<maxLines; i++) {
        String addressStr = address.get(0).getAddressLine(i);
        builder.append(addressStr);
        builder.append(" ");
        }

    String finalAddress = builder.toString(); //This is the complete address.
    } catch (IOException e) {}
      catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

Please if someone could help me I'll be very pleasure.
Thank's a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try {
     List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
     if (addresses.size() > 0) {
              String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
     }
    //the rest of your code
```

Comment: getLocality() is null, in some addresses city name is nowhere to be found in any of the result values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a better way to get the City name ONLY, except using `getLocality()`. When we use `getLocality()`, you can see that we have City name, country name etc. Just analyze the output of this function and you will encounter that all the bits are separated by "Comma". City name is at 0th index.

```
private void getLocation(String lat, String longt) {
String myCity = " ";
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address>addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat),Double.parseDouble(longt), 1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        myCity =  addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        Log.d("myLog", "Address: " + address);
        String arrp[] = address.split(",");
        Log.d("myLog", "City:  " + arrp[0]);

       }
catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```